# How to check which UIViewController is active

Tags: iphone

I need to check which UIViewController is active so I have implemented some cases depending upon the result.

```
[self.navigationController.visibleViewController className]
```

This always returns null.

I am checking with this statement:

```
if([iDetailController isKindOfClass:[IDetailController class]])
```

but it fails, kindly help me if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following method:

`if ([self isMemberOfClass:[IDetailController class]])
{`

`CFShow(@"Yep, it's the IDetailController controller");
}`

isMemberOfClass tells you if the instance is an exact instance of that class. There's also isKindOfClass:

`if ([self isKindOfClass:[BaseView class]])
{`

```
CFShow(@"This will log for all classes that extend BaseView");`
```

`}`

isKind tests that the class is a extension of a certain class.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[self.navigationController.topViewController class]` to get active view controller's class. So `if ([self.navigationController.topViewController isMemberOfClass:[IDetailController class]]) {...}` should work.